# Using N1QL reserved words

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have a document with the structure { doc.data.role.level }, I want to access to level property,
but using this query

```
SELECT r.data.role.level    FROM `hostel` r where r.id = '12345678Z'
```

I got the error

```
"msg": "syntax error - at role",
```

but with those query I got no results

```
SELECT r.data.`role`.level  FROM `hostel` r where r.id = '12345678Z'
SELECT `r.data.role.level`  FROM `hostel` r where r.id = '12345678Z'
```

Comment: Please post the sample document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are special characters in fields/identifiers or reserve keywords you must escape them with back-ticks(i.e. escaped identifiers) as described  https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/identifiers.html

Example 1:
     "role" is reserve keyword

```
{
 "id":"12345678Z",
 "data":{"role":{"level":3}}
}

SELECT r.data.`role`.level
FROM hostel AS r
WHERE r.id = "12345678Z";
```

Example 2:
    Field has special character dot. You must escape whole field name (to interpret as field vs nested document).

```
{
 "id":"12345678Z",
 "data.role.level":5
}

SELECT r.`data.role.level`
FROM hostel AS r
WHERE r.id = "12345678Z";
```

Example 3:
    hostels is array. If you are looking inside array you must use ANY syntax.

```
{
 "hostels": [ { "id":"12345678Z"},
              { "id":"34545678Z"}}
            ]
 "data":{"role":{"level":3}}
}

SELECT r.data.`role`.level
FROM hostel AS r
WHERE ANY h IN r.hostels SATISFIES h.id = "12345678Z" END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with backticks to escape reserved words.

If you aren't getting an error message, then I suspect it's your `WHERE` clause. Are you sure your documents have an "id" field in them?

```
{ "id": "12345678Z", "foo": "bar", ... etc ... }
```

Or are you trying to query based on the document ID (in the below screenshot there is no "id" field in the document)?

[image]

If the latter, then you should use META().id:

```
SELECT * FROM `testbucket` r where META(r).id = '12345678Z'
```

I know this might seem a bit confusing, but "id" isn't a magic field in Couchbase. It's a field just like any other. The actual ID of the document is in the document's *metadata*.

Also, a recommendation: if you are trying to get a *single* document by *its ID*, you're much better off using the key/value API instead of a N1QL query. No need to involve the overhead of query/index services.